# How to include paths for Webpack Dev Server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to load files from the project's root directory while utilizing a nested directory structure to host the example (Location to run the webpack dev server).

## webpack dev server

```js
devServer: {
    colors:             true,
    contentBase:        './example',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline:             true,
    progress:           true
}
```

## example/index.html

```html
<!-- how do i access you `node_modules`! -->
<link href="node_modules/path/to/file.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="node_modules/path/to/file.js"></script>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Is there anyway to achieve this, beyond setting contentBase to `.` (root)?

Comment: You can set `resolve.root` or `resolve. modulesDirectories` to achieve this.

Comment: @arturkin How do you suppose?